# Problem in running brown driver?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Every time when I need to start the brown_drivers irobot_create_2_1 I need to change the port /dev/ttyS0 to /dev/ttyACM0 using terminal command.

```
rosparam set /brown/irobot_create_2_1/port /dev/ttyACM0
```

moreover I need to get permission to open the port ttyACM0 (using terminal command as bellow) as my user at ubuntu system do not have access.

```
sudo chmod 0777 /dev/ttyACM0
```

**Please tell me what change should I make in driver.py node of irobot_create_2_1 package so that I need not to change the port from /dev/ttyS0 to /dev/ttyACM0 every time?**
**Please do tell me how I can get permanent access to open the port /dev/ttyACM0.**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66854/problem-in-running-brown-driver-?/) by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2013-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you need to write a udev rule. udev can map new devices to whatever name you want and can even change permissions. There are lots of guides on the interwebs for how to do this, and [this one](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) should get you started.  Good luck.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-09**:
I had a first look on to the link. It seems to be very helpful. I hope to get it done. Thank you.